# removing underline of a link

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website at the moment but my underline of the link in my navigation menu won't go away.

**HTML:**

```
<header>


<ul>
  <li class="first-nav"><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="portofolio.html">PORTOFOLIO</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
 </ul>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

Comment: What does this have to do with either JavaScript or jQuery? Can't you simply remove the text-decoration CSS?

Comment: [text-decoration](http://bit.ly/1zdJvUY)

Comment: look at the css a: tags at the bottom of my css http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/main.css

you want text decoration: none

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple add this css rule

```
a{text-decoration:none}
```

using inline method

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/" style="text-decoration:none">link</a>
```